# Is there a VRML2 (VRML97 / WRL) viewer?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a VRML2 (VRML97) viewer that works out of the box for Ubuntu? I've heard about  `g3dviewer` (no support for VRML2), and also about `freeWRL`, `whitedune` and [VRMLViewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vrmlviewer/) - but I cannot find any .debs of these, and it seems their building from source is rather involved.

`blender` can import these files - but I'd want a quick viewer here; if I have a directory with 4-5 wrl files, I have to import each in blender, then delete everything from blender so I can load and display the next one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As of Ubuntu Trusty 14.04, view3dscene is also packaged, as discussed at this (duplicate) question: [(VRML) Files, How to Render - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181721/vrml-files-how-to-render).  It has a much more intuitive interface than whitedune for simple viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 10.04.3 LTS and 11.10 oneiric have whitedune and it seems to work ok. Install it with a package manager or `sudo apt-get install whitedune`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for that @taneli - I almost thought I'd never get an answer to this :) Cheers!