# (VRML) Files, How to Render

Tags: package-management, 3d, education

How can i render (VRML) Files.

From here http://csi.chemie.tu-darmstadt.de/ak/immel/script/redirect.cgi?filename=http://csi.chemie.tu-darmstadt.de/ak/immel/tutorials/orbitals/vrml.html

http://csi.chemie.tu-darmstadt.de/ak/immel/tutorials/orbitals/vrml/1s.wrl

I am unable to play these file in Chrome Current Version, Ubuntu 12.04.
Also, is there any way to get these models to work in any 3d molecule viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used these files, but after some googling i came up with [this site](http://cic.nist.gov/vrml/vbdetect.html) which lists some vrml/x3d viewers. I have tried the InstantPlayer binaries for ubuntu, but I couldn't get it to open the 1s.wrl file from your link.

But the [view3dscene](http://castle-engine.sourceforge.net/view3dscene.php) worked for me. On this page you can find the binaries for both 32-bit and 64-bit Ubuntu.

It's a bit ugly, but seems to work. Here is what it looks like on my computer:
[image]

Comment: Does this work in chrome?

Comment: view3dscene is packaged in the standard ubuntu archive for safe, convenient installation via your choice of package management tools as of Trusty 14.04 LTS.  As noted in [Is there a VRML2 (VRML97 / WRL) viewer? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36935/is-there-a-vrml2-vrml97-wrl-viewer), whitedune is an option in earlier versions of Ubuntu, back to lucid 11.10, but the interface in view3dscene is much more intuitive.